# C++ objects created without new keyword but new keyword used in constructor

Tags: c++

If I create an object without using the new keyword such as 'Object s(someval)', but that objects constructor uses new, when that object goes out of scope, will the destructor be called for it's new allocation?  I feel as though it is, but I'm unsure.

Comment: which object are you talking about going out of scope? the one created on stack or the one on heap?

Comment: @nommyravian: Dynamically allocated objects don't have scope, their lifetime continues until they are explicitly freed (or the memory is reused).

Answer (score 3):

Let’s give names to the objects, shall we?

```
struct A {
    A() b(new B) {}
    B* b;
    C c;
};

A a;
```

Here, `a`’s destructor **is** called. So is `A::c`’s destructor (which is called automatically when `a` is destructed).

However, `*A::b`’s destructor is **not** called – actually, the pointer object `A::b` *itself* is properly released but since it’s a primitive type (it’s a pointer!) nothing happens. The *pointee* `*A::b` however needs to be manually destructed (and its memory released) by calling `delete`.

Comment: I think the short answer in bold should be "no", because the question is "will the destructor be called for it's new allocation?" I think the OP means the allocated object, not the pointer

Comment: @Andy Well the question is what “its” refers to. I understood it to refer to the outer object. But I’ll amend …

Answer (score 2):

> when that object goes out of scope, will the destructor be called for it's new allocation?

It depends on how `Object` is defined.

If the pointer returned by `new` is stored in some data member of `Object` on which `delete` gets called by the destructor of `Object` itself, **then yes**, the object allocated with `new` will be destroyed as well when `s` goes out of scope.

**Otherwise, no**. Every call to `new` must be matched by a corresponding call to `delete` before you lose the last pointer/reference to the allocated object, otherwise you will have a *memory leak*.

Since it is easy to fail to do so, and since it is also easy to dereference by mistake a pointer which is dangling (i.e. pointing to an object whose lifetime has ended), it is usually  preferable to **avoid performing manual memory management through raw pointers, `new` and `delete`** (or their array counterparts).

When you need to control an object's lifetime, always prefer using RAII wrappers such as `std::shared_ptr<>` or `std::unique_ptr<>` unless you really know what you are doing and can't do otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

No, you have to explicitly `delete` it in the destructor if you store that dynamically-allocated pointer as a data member. This also introduces the Rule of Three (Rule of Five in C++11), which is a bother. This is why stack-allocated objects should be preferred when possible.

When a pointer is necessary, make use of an RAII wrapper, such as `std::vector` for a dynamically-allocated array or a smart pointer, such as `std::unique_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr`, for a single dynamically-allocated object. These manage the memory for you and to you, it's no extra work.

Answer (score 0):

No, it won't...
You have to define the `delete` in your destructor of the object you allocated using `new`.
You create an object on the heap using `new` and when your object is destroyed you will lose the reference to the object creating a memory-leak.
To avoid this, you might use a smart-pointer like `shared_ptr`.

Answer (score 0):

No you will have to call delete explicitly for that object in the destructor